# VBScripting error, expected then and expected end?

Tags: vbscript

I am having all kinds of problems with VBScript. It seems to be originating at the If Then statements. This is the code...

```
Option Explicit
Dim User, Pass

User=InputBox("Username")
If User = Guest then
 msgbox "hi"
```

It just doesn't work and its giving me the error code 800A03F6
What do I need to do to fix this? The error is on line 6.

Answer (score 2):

Either this .....

```
Option Explicit
Dim User
User = InputBox("Username")
If User = "Guest" then
  MsgBox "hi"
End If
```

Or ...

```
  Option Explicit
    Dim User
    User = InputBox("Username")
    If User = "Guest" then MsgBox "hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a string as a variable, and it isn't one (at least from the code you posted). `Guest` is not declared at all. You need to quote the string.

Try this instead:

```
User = InputBox("Username")
If User = "Guest" then
  MsgBox "hi"
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed to do the whole time. I just needed to quote my strings.